# vector manipulation in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector of growing integers:

```
data = np.arange(6) + 1
```

I want to organize it in a bigger vector to the following indices:

```
dataIdx = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

The result would then be:

```
array([1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

I can use a for-loop, but I am looking for a one-liner or two-liners.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Can you write more concrete the individual steps? I don't understand how line 1 and 2 result in line 3.

Comment: What if the number of ones is larger than the length of `data`?

Comment: `dataIdx[dataIdx > 0] = np.arange(1, np.count_nonzero(dataIdx)+1)` gives your desired output but I'm not sure if it's suitable for a general case because I also don't understand what rule you're applying.

Comment: Thanks you @roganjosh, it is exactly what I wanted, I just couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
In [53]: ind = np.where(dataIdx != 0)[0]

In [55]: z = np.zeros(dataIdx.size)

In [57]: z[ind] = data

In [58]: z
Out[58]: array([1., 2., 0., 3., 4., 0., 0., 5., 6.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`cumsum`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and a mask:

```
dataIdx[dataIdx!=0] = dataIdx[dataIdx!=0].cumsum()
# array([1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

More general with lists:

```
from collections import deque

a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b_list = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]

a_queue = deque(a_list)

d_list = [a_queue.popleft() if i else 0 for i in b_list ]

print(d_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the `where` answer - turn `DataIdx` into a boolean mask with `astype`:

```
In [97]: data=np.arange(1,7)
In [98]: dataIdx = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
In [99]: res = np.zeros(dataIdx.shape, data.dtype)
```

We don't want to index with the integer array

```
# In [100]: res[dataIdx] 
# Out[100]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

But make it boolean, with `astype`, or with `dataIdx==1`:

```
In [101]: res[dataIdx.astype(bool)]
Out[101]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [102]: res[dataIdx.astype(bool)]=data
In [103]: res
Out[103]: array([1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

`np.place(res, dataIdx.astype(bool), data)` also works.